# Windows 7 Pagefile

Tags: windows-7, pagefile

What is the maximum size for a "System Managed" pagefile on Windows 7 x64?

I usually set my pagefile to be able to use the rest of the space on my drive if need be, but I've noticed that mine is currently set to "System Managed" and wanted to know if theres an upper limit with this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum: 1× your amount of RAM. Maximum: 3× your amount of RAM or 4GB, whichever is the **larger**. As explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2860880) (scroll down to around the middle of the page).

Comment: The minimum can be less than 1x your RAM. That just means you can not dump core

Comment: @Hennes That appears to be the case only in Windows 8 and up. The question is about Windows 7, for which according to the cited source (MS KB article) this answer is correct. Note that it's also about *system* managed page files only.